# Objective C: Received Memory Warning on ARC

Tags: objective-c, ios, memory, automatic-ref-counting

I am having memory warning with my app then it crashes. The error, I think is on my draw-on-touch feature, because when I tried to run it with the alloc instrument the memory starts increasing when i keep on moving my finger on the screen.

Here's my code.

```
    touchSwiped = YES;

    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];

    previousPoint2 = previousPoint1;
    previousPoint1 = currentTouch;
    currentTouch = [touch locationInView:self.view];

    CGPoint mid1 = midPoint(previousPoint2, previousPoint1); 
    CGPoint mid2 = midPoint(currentTouch, previousPoint1);

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(480 , 320));
    [drawView.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 480,320)];  

    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();    

    CGContextSetLineCap(context,kCGLineCapRound);
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, inkWidth);
    CGContextSetBlendMode(context, blendMode);
    CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(context,redColor, greenColor, blueColor, 1);
    CGContextBeginPath(context);
    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, mid1.x, mid1.y);
    CGContextAddQuadCurveToPoint(context, previousPoint1.x, previousPoint1.y, mid2.x, mid2.y);
    CGContextStrokePath(context);

    drawView.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
```

Comment: You are creating a whole lot of stuff for every touch/drag, even with ARC, I believe you have to release CGContextRef and some other stuff. I am not completely sure, hence this is a comment. Good luck!

Comment: You are half-correct, @ohr. Core Graphics and Core Foundation "objects" aren't memory managed by ARC, but the `CGContextRef` you get from `UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()` isn't owned by the caller (the function doesn't [have `copy` or `create` in its name](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFMemoryMgmt/Concepts/Ownership.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001148-103029)), and doesn't have to be released.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I did what Ohr's said on his comment and it worked for me.

I released the `CGContextRef` like this `CGContextRelease(context);`

Comment: @Jesper's answer is correct. You should not release an object that you did not retained

Answer (score 2):

When using `UIGraphicsBeginImageContext`, you should always balance it with `UIGraphicsEndImageContext` after you're done using it or it won't be cleaned up neatly. Code running following your method would still believe that the current UI context is the one that you've released manually with potentially disastrous results.